# JavaScript - Detect index of Element being clicked in NodeLIst

Tags: javascript, function, unique

I Have created a NodeList by obtaining HTML elements with a shared className by:

```
> var btn = document.getElementsbyClassName("btn")
```

This is the HTML code:

```
 <div id="main">
    <div class="btn">
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Thus this particular NodeList object has a length of 4.

Now I want to invoke a function when one of this elements is being clicked. I accomplish that by using a for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < btn.length ; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = doSomething;
};

function doSomething() {
  // here come some code.
};
```

But how can I obtain the index of the NodeList on which te event was fired? And how can I assign unique names for each of the elements of the array?

Comment: in addition: what if the code of the doSomething() function would be: btn[1].innerHTML = //Index of item being clicked

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < btn.length ; i++) {
    btn[i].id = "btn"+i;
    if(btn[i].className=="btn")
        btn[i].onclick = doSomething;
};

function doSomething() {
    var num = this.id.substr(3);
  alert("Div " + num + " clicked");
};
```

(I took out getElementsByClassName() to make it cross browser. That is of course assuming you haven't implemented your own override for the method to make it cross browser).

**Edit:** For your innerHTML question, check out the attached fiddle to see it working fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/TdCD8/

Comment: thx, this was helpfull indeed. I was having trouble with assigning an unique name to each to the classnames. And this code solves exacly that. This was good brainfood :)

Comment: Glad it helped :) In the loop, it would be more efficient to put btn[i] into a variable so you don't have to pull from the array every time, but the performance difference would likely not be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can include it in the function signature :

```
for(var i = 0; i < btn.length ; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = doSomething(i);
};

function doSomething(i) {
    return function() {
        btn[1].innerHTML = i;
    }
};
```

Comment: That would not work: because if you pass an argument to the doSomething() function, the function will be invoked before the event.

Comment: True, but it's returning a function, so wouldn't the onclick property still get assigned an event handler?

Comment: @BarendHuberts : no the closure will encapsulate the variable... You can check this here : http://jsfiddle.net/8xXRu/.

Comment: @BarendHuberts : updated fiddle with the content of the first item containing the item clicked : http://jsfiddle.net/8xXRu/3/